# Position QDialog under ModelIndex clicked

Tags: python, pyside

How can i properly position the popup dialog under the ModelIndex clicked in a QTreeView. The X position, width and height of the popup dialog appear correct. However the Y position i can't seem to get correct. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

```
import os, sys, pprint
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800, 400)

        self.uiSearch = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.uiItems = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.uiItems.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiItems.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.uiItems.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.uiItems.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiSearch)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiItems)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        for i in range(10):
            col1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item' + str(i))
            col2 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item' + str(i))
            col3 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item' + str(i))
            self.uiItems.model().appendRow([col1,col2,col3])

        self.uiItems.clicked.connect(self.clickedItem)


    def clickedItem(self, index):
        print index
        if index.isValid():
            rect = self.uiItems.visualRect(index)
            pos = self.uiItems.mapToGlobal(rect.bottomLeft())

            # create editor
            dlg = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)
            dlg.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
            dlg.resize(rect.width(), 100)
            dlg.move(pos)
            dlg.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visualRect()` is respect to the `viewport()`, not the QTreeView (the QTreeView is headers + viewport):

```
def clickedItem(self, index):
    if index.isValid():
        rect = self.uiItems.visualRect(index)
        pos = self.uiItems.viewport().mapToGlobal(rect.bottomLeft())
        # create editor
        dlg = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)
        dlg.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        dlg.resize(rect.width(), 100)
        dlg.move(pos)
        dlg.show()
```